# Sidebar with emberjs and symfony2

Tags: symfony, ember.js, twig

I want to create a web app with emberjs and symfony2. Where is the best choice for an sidebar in all page of my application ? At this time have an layout (twig) with the sidebar and a content div when I loading the content with emberjs.